# prove $ \lim_{x \to 1^{-}} \frac{1}{x\left(1 - x\right)} = \infty $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I want to prove that $ \lim_{x \to 1^{-}} \frac{1}{x\left(1 - x\right)} = \infty $. Here's what I tried.

Given $ M \gt 0 $, Choose $ \delta = $

Suppose $ -\delta \lt x - 1 \lt 0 $

Check:

$ \frac{1}{x\left(1 - x\right)} \gt M $

$ x\left(1 - x\right) \lt M $

$ x - x^2 \lt M $

But I don't understand how to continue from here.

Comment: The first sentence is not complete in what you tried: "Choose $\delta=$" what?

Comment: You mean $x(1-x) < \frac{1}{M}$. (Which is true if both sides are positive; I'd at least mention they are.) Hint: $-\delta < x-1$ lets you know something about $x$, which then gets multiplied by $1-x$.

Comment: @user1046533 It's one working way of writing a $\delta$-$\epsilon$ proof, with a blank to be filled in later when an appropriate $\delta$ is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work out an "$\epsilon$-$\delta$" type proof, one should not think in terms of solving an exact inequality algebraically. While it works in some simple cases such as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$, it does not work in most cases.

---

Given $M>0$. You want to find $\delta>0$ such that if $0<1-x<\delta$, then
$$
\frac{1}{x(1-x)}=\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x}>M\tag{*}
$$

The intuition is that if $x$ is close to $1$ from the left, then

- $\dfrac1{1-x}$ would be "very big"
- $\dfrac{1}{x}$ would not be "small" (aka "away from zero")

If you choose $\delta=\frac1M$, then
$$
0<1-x<\delta \implies 0<1-x<\frac1M \implies \frac{1}{1-x}>M\tag{1}
$$

Now if you can further make $\frac1x\ge 1$, you are done. The constraint $0<1-x<\delta$ in (1) is equivalent to
$$
1-\delta<x<1\tag{2}
$$
If $\delta\le \frac12$, then (2) implies $\frac1x\ge 1$.

So putting everything together, you can choose $\delta=\min\{\frac1M,\frac12\}$ to get (*).

Answer (score 0):

Note that if $\frac12<x<1$, then $\frac1x>2$, and therefore$$\frac1{x(1-x)}>\frac2{1-x}.$$On the other hand, assuming that $x<1$,$$\frac2{1-x}>M\iff 1-x<\frac2M\iff x>1-\frac2M.$$So, take $\delta>\max\left\{\frac12,\frac2M\right\}$, and then$$1-\delta<x<1\implies\frac1{x(1-x)}>\frac2{1-x}>M.$$